# iOS swift keyboard with growing input area above it

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, storyboard, textarea

What would be a good way to implement a growing text-area connected to the keyboard, like the facebook-app?

[image]

How do i set the constraints in the storyboard? As this should be connected to the keyboard which is not in the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with self sizing UITableViewCell.

Take a look on this tutorial:
https://pontifex.azurewebsites.net/self-sizing-uitableviewcell-with-uitextview-in-ios-8/